# What happens to property values on an object in JavaScript when its property values change during asynchronous function calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am wondering what happens to a javascript object that is passed to an asynchronous function (like a database save), and then immediately has its property's value changed.

The reason I am interested in this is that the asynchronous code takes a long time to finish and so waiting for it to callback would take longer than I would like to respond.

Take the following code:

```
function asyncDatabaseSave(user) {
// Save the user asynchronously in the database   
// Do things that take a lot of time before calling back
}

app.get(function (req, res) {
    // In real code user is an object that gets passed in.
    user = {cart: [1, 2, 3]};
    // What is the value of user.cart going to be when it reaches the databaseSave call?
    // At the time of the function call, user.cart has options but it is set to null immediately after
    asyncDatabaseSave(user);
    user.cart = null;
    res.json(user);
})
```

I think that the "correct" way to ensure that the user object was saved with the cart not `null` and then clear it would be to pass a callback into `asyncDatabaseSave` to set it to `null` after the save.

However I am interested in calling `res.json` as soon as possible.  I have also experimented with this code:

```
app.get(function (req, res) {
    var items = user.cart;
    user.cart = null;
    res.json(user);
    asyncDatabaseSave(user, items);
})
```

This way `items` is stored as a separate var and passed into a slightly-modified database save function.

What happens to `user.cart` when `asyncDatabaseSave` is called and then it is set to `null` immediately after?

If I am trying to save `user` with cart, but also return the `user` with cart set to `null` what is the best way to do this?

Comment: If it is `asynchronous` you need to wait unless if returns `fulfilled-promise` or do the stuff in `callbacks`

Comment: You could clone the user object. One of the many ways to do this is `var newUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens to user.cart when asyncDatabaseSave is called and then it
>   is set to null immediately after?

You'd have to know what actually happens in the async database call to know whether it's safe to modify the passed in object immediately after making the call or not.  There are many cases where the operative parts of the `user` object would already be copied into native code and sent off to the database before `asyncDatabaseSave()` returns so further modifying the `user` object would not affect the async call at all.

But, there are situations where you can't assume that, particular if `asyncDatabaseSave()` is actually made up of several async calls and some Javascript runs between them (such as opening the db, then writing to the db.  In those cases, modifying the `user` object where you are could affect things.

> If I am trying to save user with cart, but also return the user with
>   cart set to null what is the best way to do this?

So, to be safe, don't modify the `user` object right after `asyncDatabaseSave(user)`.

If you really just want to call `res.json(user)` as fast as possible, then you can just make a copy of the `user` object, modify that copy and then use each separate copy in your two async operations.  That's the general answer that works in all cases and it's the safe way to do things.

If the whole `cart` object is not needed in `asyncDatabaseSave()`, then picking out just the parts that are needed and passing those (like your last suggestion), allows you to freely assign `cart` properties afterwards without any risk.  You do have to be careful that you aren't reaching into the `cart` object and changing objects in the `cart` object because that might be changing the same objects that you passed to `asyncDatabaseSave()`, but you can certainly assign properties to the `cart` object and that will not affect `asyncDatabaseSave()` if you didn't pass it the `cart` object.

Here's a simple example to show how it's not safe to assume you can modify the object you passed in:

```js
function someAsyncSave(u) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       log(u.name)
   }, 50);
}

var user = {name: "Joe"};

someAsyncSave(user);
user.name = "Alice";
```

```html
<script src="http://files.the-friend-family.com/log.js"></script>
```

Run the snippet.  It will log "Alice", even though the property was "Joe" when `someAsyncSave()` was called.

Even though the `user` object had `user.name = "Joe"` when it was passed to `someAsyncSave()`, by the time `someAsyncSave()` actually uses the property, it has already been changed by the outer code.

Comment: Great answer. Does the first part of your answer refer to @ste2425's comment. His comment is compelling.

Comment: @Startec - I don't quite agree with ste2425's comment. Objects are passed by pointer so modifying a property of the object outside the function CAN affect what the function is using inside the function if it has multiple asynchronous async operations inside. Both inside and outside can be referring to the same underlying object and modifying it in one place can affect the other. As my answer says, it depends upon the implementation inside of `asyncDatabaseSave()` whether this is an issue or not. I could show you implementations where it does matter or implementations where it does not matter.

Comment: @jfriend00 Embarrassingly your correct. My fiddle worked i believe because i was performing `x = {y: 50};` instead of `x.y = 50;`. When i do the latter it behaves as you said. Also it states it here on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_declarations)

Comment: @Startec - Example added to my answer.